# I written a function for if i written a string it throw the character in output. But i have showing error which i commening in the last of Code

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION string_to_char (
    c1 NUMBER,
    c2 VARCHAR2,
    c3 VARCHAR2
) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS

    c1 NUMBER := 1;
    c2 VARCHAR2(20);
    c3 VARCHAR2(20) := ( '&c3' );
BEGIN
    FOR c1 IN 1..20 LOOP
        SELECT
            substr(c3, c1, 1)
        INTO c2
        FROM
            dual;

        dbms_output.put_line(c2);
    END LOOP;
END;

/*
Function STRING_TO_CHAR compiled

LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
0/0       PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
1/1       PLS-00410: duplicate fields in RECORD,TABLE or argument list are not permitted
Errors: check compiler log
*/
```

Comment: Provide a full description of your problem, your tests, inputs, current outputs and required outputs

Answer (score 1):

You named too many things with the same name (`c1` in your case):

- function's parameter
- local variable
- counter in FOR loop

If you modified it to e.g.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION string_to_char (c1  NUMBER,
  2                                             c2  VARCHAR2,
  3                                             c3  VARCHAR2)
  4     RETURN VARCHAR2
  5  IS
  6     pc1  NUMBER := 1;
  7     pc2  VARCHAR2 (20);
  8     pc3  VARCHAR2 (20) := c3;
  9  BEGIN
 10     FOR i IN 1 .. 20
 11     LOOP
 12        SELECT SUBSTR (c3, c1, 1) INTO pc2 FROM DUAL;
 13
 14        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (pc2);
 15     END LOOP;
 16
 17     RETURN pc2;
 18  END;
 19  /

Function created.

SQL>
```

then it compiles and works (although, I'm not sure I understand what is its purpose):

```
SQL> SELECT string_to_char (1, 'A', 'B') FROM DUAL;

STRING_TO_CHAR(1,'A','B')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
B

B
B
B
B
B
B
B
B
B
B
B
B
B
B
B
B
B
B
B
B
SQL>
```

Comment: This Code not giving Required Result

Comment: I have no idea what is "required result" for you. I just tried to tell you which **errors** you made, which prevented function to be compiled in the first place. With that many "c1" you used, I can't even guess what you wanted to do as **you didn't describe the requirement**, nor provided any sample data, nor provided desired result. As my crystal ball is broken, sorry - write your own code that will give required result (as you probably know what you want; I don't).

Comment: Okay I again Publish the question